# How does sync() work? Best way to monitor size changes of a file in C++?

Tags: c++, synchronization, filesystems, filesize, inotify

In C++, I'm trying to monitor changes in a file size. Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346423/best-way-to-sync-a-file-with-changing-data), I have a large file (e.g. 100MB) on which small data (e.g. 128 bytes) gets added by an external process (on which I don't have access/control) very frequently (e.g. every 1ms).

Currently, I use sync(), seekg() and tellg():

```cpp
std::string FilePath = "path of file";
std::streampos NewFileSize = 0, OldFileSize = 0;
std::ifstream FileStream(FilePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

while(FileStream.good() && FileStream.is_open()) {
    FileStream.sync();
    FileStream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    NewFileSize = FileStream.tellg();
    if (NewFileSize > OldFileSize) {
        // Do stuff
    };
    OldFileSize = NewFileSize;
};
```

My questions are:

- **How does `sync()` work?** Does it discard the existing buffer completely, re-read the entire file and re-build the whole buffer? It would not be very efficient... Or does it keep the existing buffer, read only the new data and update the buffer with the new data only? Or does it update only data from the current position `tellg()` in the file?
- **Is there a more efficient cross-platform way to monitor frequent file changes?** An infinite loop with `sync()` seems like an inefficient drain of resources. Monitoring the cached size of the file with `std::filesystem` would not work, as it is not updated in real-time. And `inotify` is not cross-platform.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at some kind of third-party library for portable file notifications?

Comment: Also, while there's no (nice) portable way to get the size of a file, why not simply use conditional compilation to use e.g. [`stat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html) on POSIX systems (like Linux and macOS), or its equivalent on Windows?

Comment: Maybe you should get familiar with named pipes. This way programs which are just using files, can communicate directly without temporary file. Named pipe can be created by script which will start two processes one will read second write to named pipe.

Comment: @MarekR Unfortunately, I don't have access to the process writing the file... Unless I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, I will look at third-party libraries. A quick search directed me to [efsw](https://github.com/SpartanJ/efsw). Any recommendation?

Comment: While not cross platform, look into `inotify` on Linux (and Windows has similar APIs for NTFS).

Comment: @ThibaultDC yes you misunderstood comment. To use named pipes you do not need alter application.

Comment: I aso found [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) and [libuv (in C)](https://github.com/libuv/libuv)

Comment: how about doing a read()  on the file descriptor (if your OS supports such a thing) in a loop? I think thats how the  posix "tail" command works

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `std::filesystem::file_size` exists since C++17.  (Of course, you can’t make another process flush, and POSIX `sync` is not portable.)